# Efficient way to check if every string in a list appear in another list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 massive lists of strings:

One that has names of chemicals (like 10K chemicals):

```
chemicals_list = ["chemical1", "chemical2", ..., "chemical100000"]
```

And another that contains articles abstracts (like 50M abstracts):

```
abstracts_list = ["abstract1 is very very very long", "abstract2 is very very very VERY long", ..., "abstract50000000 is pretty long as well"]
```

I need to create a frequency dictionary that maps each chemical from the `chemicals_list` to in how many abstracts it appeared in.

Currently I have 2 for loops, but this is taking forever:

```
frequency_dict = {}
for c in chemicals_list:
    exact_entity = f' {c} ' # make sure it's the exact entity since it can appear as a substring (e.g., "pen" rather then "penicilin")
    for abstract_text in abstracts_list: 
        if exact_entity in abstract_text:
            if c in frequency_dict.keys():
                frequency_dict[c] += 1
            else: 
                frequency_dict[c] = 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have access to a GPU if that helps

Comment: you could break the list of abstracts into parts and do parallel processing to get through it faster, that would be helped by the fact you have a gpu to give you more treads to run

Answer (score 1):

I optimized your code the following way:

```py
chemicals_list = ["chemical1", "chemical2", ..., "chemical100000"]

abstracts_list = ["abstract1 is very very very long", "abstract2 is very very very VERY long", ..., "abstract50000000 is pretty long as well"]

frequency_dict = {}
text = ' '.join(abstracts_list)  # make one big string
for c in chemicals_list:
    # you might want to consider fuzzy word matching (see fuzzywuzzy python lib)
    frequency_dict[c] = text.count(c)
```

I ran a test locally and I saw a massive speed improvement in my test case. It's a good idea to avoid python loops if you want perfomance. There might even exist some function so that no python loop is needed, but I didn't really search. Also try using numpy/scipy where you can so you can use precompiled c functions. When you have tried all of that, then you can start thinking of multithreading.

Also consider posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where it's more appropriate to ask for a review/improvement.

Comment: Oh cool, I wasn't familiar with https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Testing the code now

Comment: Getting `MemoryError` when trying to run `text = ' '.join(abstracts_list) `

Comment: I found following SO post which handled the same issue you are having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475387/python-string-counting-memory-error . Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks very relevant, trying it now! Thanks for the help : )

Comment: Just want to point out that the `string`, `time` and `random` module imports are redundant

Comment: Yea I wasn't importing them. From the SO link you shared and the same code you have I'm currently using chunking to overcome the problem with the memory error. Seems okay for now. It's still be pretty slow but better than before